# How to set the copy of Sample Workflow to items right way?

Tags: workflow

I have created copy of the Sample Workflow and rename it to (e.g. to) XYZ Default. Then I assigned it to field Default Workflow of all templates.
And when I create new item based on template with my XYZ Default workflow, I see the following values in fields:

Workflow: Workflows/XYZ Default
State: Workflows/Sample Workflow/Draft
Default workflow: Workflows/XYZ Default

Why I see value Workflows/Sample Workflow/Draft in State field, not Workflows/XYZ Default/Draf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you crated a copy of a workflow you copied all fields as well. Your workflow stores Initial workflow state and next steps in a fields. 
To fix it, go to your new workflow and update fields.

First go to your `XYZ Default` item and update `Initial state` field.
Then go to each workflow's `Command` items and update `Next state` field.